# How to make meteor-npm to share the same local repo as npm?

Tags: meteor, npm

I'm having a problem that each time I run `meteor-npm` (it's run inside of a script I run every day), npm dependencies are downloaded again over the internet, which seems like a waste of time.

How can this be avoided?

Is it possible to share my local npm repository, so it will take the dependencies from there instead of internet each time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supposed to happen. It can happen if:

1. Your permissions are not set correctly
2. You share the project with someone else and have not gitignored files correctly (e.g stuff in the .meteor folder) - This makes their meteor run on a different version and clear the npm cache out.
3. You updated your version of meteor or a package with npm dependencies
4. Somehow the files in the hidden .npm directories on your machine are being deleted or ignored depending on your setup.

Also you don't have to run `meteor-npm` anymore, just the first time when you add the `meteor-npm` package to your project.

If your npm packages are included in the package.json file and you have the npm package installed in your project, you can just run `meteor` (thats meteor on its own, as if trying to start your app) and it should use the cached versions if available & if not download them the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer! running meteor-npm deletes the modules from my .npm directories?